# Positioning a Button Under a Recycler View In Constraint Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm facing an issue when I'm trying to position an edit text under a recycler view, the position of the edit text is at the bottom of the screen, and above the edit text the recycler view is placed, please refer the image

[image: screenshot]

The preview in the android studio shows my desired view, with a scrollable recycler view above the edit text.

My problem is the recycler view should be constrained above the edit text, so the edit text should be always visible on the screen, and it should not be moved down when the number of items in the recycler view increases, ex the no of items in the recycler view is 10 and the no of items visible on the preview is 9 and to see the 10th item I have to scroll, but still the edit text outside the recycler view will be visible on the screen. as a fixed position which is at the bottom of the screen

this is the code

```
  `   

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Select"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/horizontal_barrier"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_header"
            tools:itemCount="10"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_list" />
    
        <android.support.constraint.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_barrier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="top"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="et" />
    
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="@color/black_primary_text_color"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontal_barrier" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

`
```

I have been searching for a valid reason for this behavior, but I'm not able to find any solid answer, I have checked multiple solutions like using height as 0dp for recycler view, using layout_constraintHeight_default as a wrap for recycler view, using barriers, Guidelines but nothing worked for me, and I know that this issue can be solved in linear, relative layouts. while I have been observing this behavior in constraint layout, Can someone please Guide or point out to me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

> If your edittext is fixed at bottom then you don't need to use barrier.
>
> just give edittext start, end and bottom constraint. So, it will fixed at bottom. Now give recylerview bottom constraint at top of edittext.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Select"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/et"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_header"
        tools:itemCount="10"
        tools:listitem="@layout/layout_item_notifications" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:background="@color/bg_card"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Tried this initially, didn't work so moved towards using a barrier, by the way, it works fine on the preview in the android studio. I'm facing the issue only when running the app in a device, you have tried this in androidx  and I have tried this using the support libraries do you think that might be an issue because I tried this in androidx too and that works perfectly fine.

Comment: no, I don't think it's solved because of androidX. It should also work in support library without barrier

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused on what your problem is.

> The preview in android studio shows my desired view, with scrollable
> recycler view above the edit text, but when I run this on a real
> device, the edit text is placed below the recycler view

Isn't that what you wanted, the EditText placed below the RecyclerView?

Comment: My problem is the recycler view should be constrained above the edit text, so the edit text should be always  visible on the screen, and it should not be moved down when the number of items in the recycler view increases, ex the no of items in the recycler view is 10 and the no of items visible on the preview is 9 and to see the 10th item I have to scroll, but still the edit text outside the recycler view will be visible on the screen. as a fixed position which is at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Try this:  remove the `Barrier`, remove the top constraint for the EditText so that it is only constrained bottomToBottom of parent. Constrain the bottom of the RecyclerView to the top of the EditText.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I initially tried without the barrier, as you have mentioned, but didn't work, so went for the barrier. but facing the same issue

Comment: Can you try putting the EditText and/or the RecyclerView in a layout, and constraint the layouts to each other?

Answer (score 1):

I ran your layout xml (with androidx dependencies instead of android support libraries) and there's nothing wrong with it, It's always sticking **EDIT TEXT** to the bottom of the screen and doesn't scrolls with **Recycler view**.

If that's not the behavior you want and want to scroll **EDIT TEXT** with **Recycler view** while keeping it at the bottom, then you should wrap **EDIT TEXT & RECYCLER VIEW** inside **NestedScrollView** and set recycler view nested scrolling to false.

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Do u think that androidx will be the issue here? because for me it's scrolling along with the recycler view and I'm not able to figure out why because the preview shows it in a different way and no I don't want the edit text  to scroll with the recycler view, I want it at a fixed position which is at the bottom of the screen

Comment: With androidx libraries, your xml is working, like exactly the behaviour what you mentioned. Didn't tried it with android support libraries, Maybe be android support libraries has bug. Support libraries are depricated anyways, You should switch to androidx.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with a parent activity that has a container that was inside a nested scroll view, so when this activity was inflated inside the container the above-mentioned issue was happening. Thanks all for helping out, much appreciated.